# How to go through elements of a different page

Tags: javascript

When a link to a page is specified (eg:`var page = "https://myPAge.php"`) is it possible, to iterate through the DOM elements by using functions such as `getElementsByID("myid")` ?

Comment: Depends on the environment. In Node.js, maybe. In the browser, no.

Comment: Possible but not easy. Use Ajax to get response. Convert the response to HTML and use Javascript to add the HTML to your current page, mark it hidden. Then use document.getElementById

Comment: Is this different page on the same site? Is it on a server you control?

Comment: @melpomene No it's a completely external page.

Comment: @AmyCohen Then you can't even fetch that page (assuming normal JavaScript on a website), let alone parse it.